# Unexpected token Error while creating view that uses pivot

Tags: oracle11g, oracle10g

I'm not able to create view in oracle through a select query that uses PIVOT function
It gives the following error.I'm not able to understand what's the problem.Please help
Refer to the image at the following address for error snapshot.The error can be seen at
following address"https://www.dropbox.com/s/sq98mvfourobo7w/Error.PNG"

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your item from work (dropbox is blocked), but I ran across this issue using the create view wizard in sql developer: it would throw out an error for an unexpected token *!* PIVOT.

The workaround was to simply use CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW from the SQL worksheet and avoid the wizard.